# How to close socket connection on Ctrl-C in a python programme

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, server

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)

any_connection = False

while True:
    try:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        any_connection = True

        # keep looking
        if not data: continue

        pid = os.fork()

        if pid == 0:
            server_process(data, conn)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

if any_connection:
    print("Closing connection")
    conn.close()
```

I'm catching the `KeyboardInterrupt`signal here on an infinite-running TCP server I wrote in Python. However, even though I know it is closing the connection because it prints `Closing Connection`, when I try to re-run the server I get:

`OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use`

I have no idea what's happening because I know for sure I'm calling `conn.close()`.

And running `killall python3`doesn't fix it, I keep getting the error unless I wait for a long time or change port. Also I tried to grep all `python3` processes but I get nothing.

I'm running OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Are you sure the error code is 48 and not 98?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) the error  `OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use` occurs because 
 the previous execution of your script has left the socket in a TIME_WAIT state, and can’t be immediately reused. This can be resolved by using the `socket.SO_REUSEADDR` flag.

For eg:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to register a hook for this, something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import signal
import sys
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
        # close the socket here
        sys.exit(0)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
```

Comment: this does not work with if process is blocked on `conn.recv`. please see https://github.com/codypiersall/pynng/issues/49