# How to close Python socket running in a thread after CTRL+C?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, sockets, python-3.x

I have a multithreaded program in python and I would like to close the socket after CTRL+C (or Z). I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27360218/how-to-close-socket-connection-on-ctrl-c) and [this](http://www.ryaneguerra.com/2013/08/gracefully-closing-python-sockets-when-developing/) but none of them had worked.

When trying to re-run the program, error message appears:

> Bind failed. Error code: 98 Message Address already in use called
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 16, in
>   
>       main.connection.close() NameError: name 'main' is not defined

```
from connection import Connection
class Main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = Connection()                       
        self.connection.start()                      
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main = Main()
    except:
        main.connection.close()


import socket
import sys
import threading
import time
class Connection(threading.Thread):  
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs=None, verbose=None):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, group=group, target=target, name=name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, verbose=verbose) 

        self.server = None
        self.connection = self.start_connention()
        self.data = "null"    
        self.lock = threading.Lock()  
        self.OK = True        

    def start_connention(self):
        host = '192.168.42.1'
        port = 8888

        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) 
        print 'Socket created'

        #Bind socket to local host and port
        try:
            s.bind((host, port))
        except socket.error, msg:
            print 'Bind failed. Error code: ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
            sys.exit()  

        print 'Socket bind complete'

        #Start listening on socket
        s.listen(10)
        print 'Socket now listening on ' + str(port)

        connection, addr = s.accept()
        print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])                

        self.server = s

        return connection

    def close(self):
        print("closing")
        self.OK = False
        self.server.close()

    def run(self):
        while self.OK:            
            with self.lock:
                self.data = self.connection.recv(4096)
                print(str(self.data))
            time.sleep(0.02)


    def send(self, message):
        self.connection.sendall(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

From docs:  The KeyboardInterrupt inherits from BaseException so as to not be accidentally caught by code that catches Exception and thus prevent the interpreter from exiting. [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    try:
       main = Main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        main.connection.close()
```

Comment: It works, but after a device connects, the code in finally is immediately called, and closes the connection without pressing  CTRL+C.

Comment: Try to add to add - main.connection.run() to try block

Comment: It's very interesting: if I add main.connection.run() into the try block, the device connects, and after pressing ctrl+c the code in the finally is **not** called :O

Comment: self.connection.start() . Where start method?

Comment: It starts the thread. But after adding main.connection.run() into the try block, it was removed from the constructor

Comment: Code in finally start work after when try code finishes or programm throw exception. It mean that your code in try immediately finish and problem in this code. But if it work before and you doesn't change it try to remove finally block and write main.connection.close() to except block and change except block to ( except KeyboardInterrupt, Exception: ).

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to use `atexit` module to this stuff.
Just put this line in `__init__` and in case any python process termination a connection will be close

```
atexit.register(self.close)
```