# Upgrade address pymodbus

Tags: python-3.x, pymodbus

How can I update the address of a server configured in pymodbus, if the program is running? I tried to stop the server and start it again but an error occurs.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is your code? where is its error?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in Linux and killing your server without proper shutdown you have to write `exit` in your console for the socket get flushed.

For windows you will probably have to close the console windows completely.

It would help if you handle how you close the connection, or maybe even reuse your socket, see here:

[How to close socket connection on Ctrl-C in a python programme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27360218/how-to-close-socket-connection-on-ctrl-c-in-a-python-programme)